# Is there a way I can have Javascript tell me why a cookie wasn't set?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Here is my code for setting a cookie:

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays)
{
    alert("setting cookie!");
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + expiredays);
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) +
    ((expiredays === null) ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
}
```

I'm using Phonegap to make an app on Android phones, which should just use and set cookies like a regular browser. It doesn't seem to be setting the cookie, though, and because of the environment (on my pnone), I can't debug.

So, is there a way I can make an alert to tell me if document.cookie fails, and ideally any error message that might tell me why?

I tried just doing `alert(document.cookie)`, but it's not outputting anything, so I'm hoping there's another way to trap the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use try/catch statement:

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays)
{
    try {
       alert("setting cookie!");
       var exdate = new Date();
       exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + expiredays);
       document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) +
       ((expiredays === null) ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    } catch(error) {
      // deal with errors
      alert(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. But, forgive me that I'm not so good at this stuff... what would I put into an alert in the catch section that would inform me of the problem? Would `alert(error)` be sufficient?

Comment: @DaveMG, yeah, it should give you a string describing where your problem is. But for future i'd recommend using Firebug in Firefox or Web Inspector in Chrome and running "console.log(anything);" which will display anything you give it. It'll allow inspecting objects which might be helpful in the future.

Comment: I use Firebug in Firefox and Chrome, but the problem here is that my bug only exhibits on the phone, within the Phonegap environment. So I'm reduced to bug hunting manually, with test code and alert outputs. Thank you for the updated code :)

Comment: @DaveMG, oh, yeah, that is a real pain to debug on mobile. Some time ago i wrote a simple plugin to stringify objects and errors so i could show them right on the page. Anyway, good luck.